# Xamarin with VS 2017 - Unable to run Emulator

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to run one simple Hello World project but I see below error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.

Please advise what is wrong, snapshot attached
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for starts check out which is the smallest version of android that is accepted (you can find this in properties of your android project), and if the emulator's version of android is higher, then you have to install android sdk on your visual studio ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=vswin ).

Answer (score 0):

Try To Fix by deleting the Xamarin.Forms package and re-adding it via NuGet. Just doing it in the Android project seemed to be enough.

Or just Follow the following Link :https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/485
https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31